# CLFAD0111W what does this mean?

Tags: xpages

I got this error in the log while working with an XPage today.

CLFAD0111W: The PropertyMap was in an invalid state. evaluateValueBindings was  enabled but not disabled before the saveState phase.

Anybody know what it means?

This is from the log

```
<CommonBaseEvent creationTime="2013-02-05T14:22:52.738+01:00" globalInstanceId="ELc0a85e0a00013ca95661f6000000ca" msg="CLFAD0111W: The PropertyMap was in an invalid state. evaluateValueBindings was enabled but not disabled before the saveState phase." severity="30" version="1.0.1">
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:level" type="noValue">
    <children name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:name" type="string"> 
        <values>VARNING</values>
    </children>
</extendedDataElements>
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceClassName" type="string">
    <values>com.ibm.xsp.binding.PropertyMap</values>
</extendedDataElements>
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceMethodName" type="string">
    <values>saveRoot</values>
</extendedDataElements>
<sourceComponentId component="Expeditor 6.2" componentIdType="ProductName" instanceId="" location="qner" locationType="Hostname" subComponent="" threadId="18" componentType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<situation categoryName="ReportSituation">
    <situationType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ReportSituation" reasoningScope="INTERNAL" reportCategory="LOG"/>
</situation>
```

Comment: In which context does the error occur? Do you have a code sample?

Comment: The error-log-0.xml gets full of this error, don't know where it comes from. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Are you using RPC control?

Comment: No RPC control, any idea what it means ?

Comment: Can you paste stack of error here? it would help...

Comment: This error is raised during the *saveRoot* of the *PropertyMap*. Seems that there is something wrong with the data of one of the custom controls.

Comment: How can I find out where the problem is, what control? 
Perhaps what data ?
Add my own exception handler?

Comment: I suggest you remove all controls and add them one by one. Then you can find out which control raises the error.

Comment: They are nestled so removing one by one will be difficult.

Comment: See also this: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=66B0E7CCB0B13EE085257A2A00696A7F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for the help.

After alot of trouble shooting I found the cause of the error.

a faulty function that should do a JS Client reload for old Domino forms and a panel refresh on XPages. But in this case both where preformed, that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to something going wrong during a saveRoot of the UI serializer API.

You will need to generate HTTP thread logs and match them to when the error occurred to see what XPage is causing the issue.

Here is the related tech note on how to do that.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003598

I'd also recommend having DEBUG_THREADID=1 set so you can map threads in the console logs.

Comment: How can I read these thread logs? As I recall they where a bit strange  in format.

Comment: Should mention it in the tech note linked (Appears to be down for me at this time)

Comment: Found it at the bottom, thanks Simon. The big problem is to match between error-log , console log, XPage error log. It would be great if  the time was specified better or the debug clock displaying in the XPage log and error-log