# What do CLFAD####E or CLFAD####W indicate in XPages?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

While working in XPages many a times I have encountered error messages beginning with `CLFAD####E` and sometimes `CLFAD####W`. In my development the error messages that I have encountered look something like this:

```
SEVERE: CLFAD####E: Exception processing XPage request.
WARNING: CLFAD####W: <SOME ERROR MESSAGE>
```

I have seen specific error messages on web like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14705119/1047998) with a number replacing `#`, to be precise `CLFAD0111W`. Another example I was able to find was this [article](http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2011/two-new-interesting-clfads-in-xpages-today) with `CFLAD0246` and `CFLAD0134E`.

But I haven't been able to find what they indicate? Is there a list of `CLFAD`s which can be looked up to see what exactly the error indicates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part is an internal identifier *CLFAD*, followed by 4 numbers to identify the error. The last character identifies the type of the message:

- *I* for "Information"
- *E* for "Error"
- *W* for "Warning"

When looking in the XPages source code you will find some property files which let you identifiy a Java property containing the error code. If you search for the property, you can find the element which throws the error message.

F.e.

*CLFAD0111W* can be found in the path

com/ibm/xsp/core/core.properties

and is contained by the property

*warn.PropertyMap.ThePropertyMapwasinaninvalidstate*

Searching for this property will lead you to *com.ibm.xsp.binding.PropertyMap* and the method *saveRoot*.

Hope this helps you a little bit.